# OpenGL strange lighting/model problem

Tags: opengl, blender

I've made a .obj reader in c++ and I've tried rendering some models. I've got the whole concept from here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMWUjNE0fYI&list=PLRIWtICgwaX0u7Rf9zkZhLoLuZVfUksDP&index=9

So I've tried to copy the export settings in blender what the guy used in the video (I'm not experienced in modelling so I had troubles because I have a newer version) and I've split every edge so they staied sharp even with the smooth shader. What my model looks like in blender:
[image]

I'm not sure if this is a texture or lighting bug. The models that the guy provides in the video work just fine.

Edit:

My drawing code is this:

```
shader->Enable();
shader->SetUniformMat4f("vw_matrix", viewMatrix);
m_Model->GetVAO().Bind();
m_Model->GetIBO().Bind();
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
m_Texture->Bind();
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m_Model->GetIBO().GetCount(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
m_Texture->Unbind();
m_Model->GetVAO().Unbind();
m_Model->GetIBO().Unbind();
shader->Disable();
```

Export settings:

- Write Normals
- Include UVs
- Triangulate faces
- Objects as OBJ objects

Edit2:

I've added a pic how the model looks without edge split (above).

My vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;
in vec3 normal;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;
out vec3 surfaceNormal;
out vec3 toLightVector;

uniform mat4 pr_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 vw_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform mat4 ml_matrix = mat4(1.0);
uniform vec3 lightPosition;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 worldPosition = ml_matrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    gl_Position = pr_matrix * vw_matrix * worldPosition;
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;

    surfaceNormal = (ml_matrix * vec4(normal, 0.0)).xyz;
    toLightVector = lightPosition - worldPosition.xyz;
}
```

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, the models that the guy in the video uses render fine with your code, but none of your own models do?

Comment: @Superdoggy Yes, exactly.

Comment: Okay, in blender, try selecting everything, going to the toolbar (if it's not open, press "T") and going to Shading/UVs and press "Recalculate". Can you tell me if that works?

Comment: Right, give me a minute please.

Comment: This seems to give me the same results.

Comment: Okay. Just wondering. It almost looks as if some of your normals are flipped, so I was curious to see if that was the problem. Could you possibly include your drawing code and your Blender export settings into your question? It will be easier to help you if we don't have to guess. :P

Comment: I'll edit my post.

Comment: Okay, three more possibilities that I can think of. 1. Try selecting "Keep Vertex Order". 2. does the model render properly without edge splits? OBJ isn't the most supportive file type and there's a possibility it doesn't support them. 3. If you've got Blender version 2.5 or somewhere around there you might want to update, I think the OBJ exporter was broken at some point around there.

Comment: Does Blender have an option to show face normal directions? (e.g. as lines or something)

Comment: @immibis yes there is, press N, scroll down to Mesh Display, and under "Normals" click the "Display Face Normals as Lines" button.

Comment: I'll look into these

Comment: Are you aware that VAOs track the currently bound IBO? Something funny may happen due to the order you unbind VAO and IBO. The VAO retains the IBO you bound several lines prior, then after you unbind the VAO you unbind an IBO from the global scope (not relative to any VAO). I doubt this is your problem, but you shouldn't be doing it in that order. Frankly because VAOs track IBO, you can probably get away with binding the IBO one time when you setup your vertex pointers and never touching that state again.

Comment: Also, does your view matrix contain scaling? I think you may need to transform your normals a little bit differently, but I can't tell without your vertex shader code or how the view matrix is computed.

Comment: I'll edit my post again for more info

Comment: In the obj-exporter settings, you could also try checking "triangulate mesh". I noticed your mesh is built using quads instead of triangles, which could cause unexpected behavior in OpenGL.

Comment: I have triangulate faces. Isn't it the same?

Comment: @PeterLenkefi it should be. If you want to be sure that it's triangulating properly, just select all and press CTRL-T in edit mode.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to edit mode
2. Select all vertices (<kbd>a</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl + n</kbd> (this recalculates all normals for all faces)

export again and see if it behaves the way you want it

If that did not work, do

1. Go to edit mode
2. Select all vertices (<kbd>b</kbd>, blender keeps a tab of the hotkeys you use and increment them by 1 for every use)
3. Press <kbd>w</kbd>, select "remove doubles" (or duplicates, something to that effect)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your triangles are not all clockwise (or ccw)
this is the cause of the lighting rendering them differently.