# Strange shadow artifacts from lighting when importing blender model in opengl

Tags: opengl, glsl, blender, assimp

[image: cylinder]I'm trying to add model loading to my opengl/sdl2 renderer and I'm successfully loading meshes using assimp after following the tutorial at [learn opengl](https://learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Assimp), however when I make my own simple models and import them, the shaders seem to not work correctly and I get strange lighting artifacts in the form of lots of shadows and black areas.

I've tried to follow the advice of this
[other question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/105973/opengl-strange-lighting-model-problem)
to eliminate the problem, but it doesn't seem to work. I attached a picture of what a simple cylinder looks like when being rendered. Note that for the cube I calculated all of the normals and stuff myself and the lighting shader works just fine for it. it is only on blender meshes that the lighting is off. I attached the shader code as well

Edit:
I went and tested out a cube model made in blender and am having the same result where it seems to be calculating the normals incorrectly when exporting. I set the ambient light to black and put the light shining down on the corner of the cubes. My cube has light on both faces that it should , but blender's cube does not.
[image: Cubes]

Also notably, the light changes depending on where I position my camera as well (only on the blender cube), even though it shouldn't matter where the camera is because the light source doesn't move.

Edit 2:
I went and retested the backpack model from the learn opengl site and I'm still getting strange shadows but to a much lesser extent, I add a pic and for context, the shadows look ok, but as you can see are much darker than they reasonable should be. I think one of my calculations is happening in the wrong space but I can't figure out which calculation it is.
[image: Backpack]

Edit 3:
I've been playing around and have found that the issue lies in the specular part of my shader and I believe it is happening that way due to the specular map (or maybe lack of one) I'm not sure. I'm gonna play around with blender and see if there is a way to fix the export specular texture.

Vertex Shader:

```
#version 460 core
layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normal;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 tangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 bitangent;
layout (location = 5) in vec2 uvs;
layout (location = 6) in float opacity;

out vec2 tex_coords;
out vec4 out_color;
out vec3 frag_pos;
out vec3 out_normal;
out vec3 out_tangent;
out vec3 out_bitangent;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 proj;

void main() {
    frag_pos = vec3(model * vec4(pos, 1.0));
    out_normal = mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * normal;

    out_color = vec4(color, opacity);
    out_tangent = tangent;
    out_bitangent = bitangent;
    tex_coords = uvs;
    
    gl_Position = proj * view * vec4(frag_pos , 1.0);
}
```

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 460 core
in vec4 out_color;
in vec3 frag_pos;
in vec3 out_normal;
in vec3 in_tangent;
in vec3 in_bitangent;
in vec2 tex_coords;

out vec4 frag_color;

uniform vec3 view_pos;

struct Material {
    sampler2D ambient_tex;
    sampler2D height_tex;
    sampler2D diffuse_tex;
    sampler2D specular_tex;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
    float shininess;
};

struct Light {
    vec3 position;
    vec3 ambient;
    vec3 diffuse;
    vec3 specular;
};

uniform Material material;
uniform Light light;

void main() {
    // ambient
    vec3 ambient = (light.ambient * material.ambient) * 
                   vec3(texture(material.ambient_tex , tex_coords)); // * vec3(out_color);

    // diffuse
    vec3 norm = normalize(out_normal);
    vec3 light_dir = normalize(light.position - frag_pos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm , light_dir) , 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = (light.diffuse * material.diffuse) * (diff * vec3(texture(material.diffuse_tex , tex_coords)));

    // specular
    vec3 view_dir = normalize(view_pos - frag_pos);
    vec3 reflect_dir = reflect(-light_dir , norm);
    float spec = pow(max(dot(view_dir , reflect_dir) , 0.0) , material.shininess);
    vec3 specular = (light.specular * material.specular) * (spec * vec3(texture(material.specular_tex , tex_coords)));

    vec3 result = ambient + diffuse + specular;
    frag_color = vec4(result , 1.0) * texture(material.diffuse_tex , tex_coords);
}
```